# Remove some images and text objects from pdf

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a pdf page object with an image and a lot of text.

I want to remove that image and remove some text objects based on their contents. That is I want to get all text objects' contents, then remove some of them if they satisfied the condition.

How can I do that with [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/)? Or is there another library which allows doing that?

Answer (score 6):

To remove all images from a PDF file using PyPDF2 you can do:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

inputStream = open("src.pdf", "rb")
outputStream = open("dst.pdf", "wb")

src = PdfFileReader(inputStream)
output = PdfFileWriter()

[output.addPage(src.getPage(i)) for i in range(src.getNumPages())]
output.removeImages()

output.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: One should be really cautious here, `output.removeImages()` removes much more than merely images...

Comment: haha........ I got an empty PDF after trying the above code. My PDF was and complete image. It was not a text.